# Does Angular.js is must for building mobile app in Phonegap/ApacheCorova and Ionic framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am pretty new by of developing apache cordova/phoneGap domain. After some search i came accross to know that I can use Simple jQuery and javascript while i develop app in Cordova. I don't know Angularjs at all, but by jQuery I can build the app.

Now, I am seeing that Ionic framework is giving a structure of the mobile app by just running some command to the CLI.Tht is pretty good because that UI structure has been build by default.

Now, my Question is that, Does Ionic framework only support Angular js? Or I can use Ionic framework but can be build the app with simple jQuery?

In other words, it is possible to use ionic framework without using Angular js?

Please let me understood...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Ionic to build mobile apps and I don't think that Angular is must. Ionic is not just couple of Angular directives, it has tools built around it too. CSS and Javascript are separated, so in theory, you should be able to use something else in place of Angular and still be able to use Ionic tools. However, AFAIK, most people are using it with Angular,so, if you decide to go this route, you'll be all by your own.

Have a look at following thread, and they should give you fair amount of idea about this:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/does-anyone-use-ionic-without-angularjs/8485
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/325

-Thanks